# Magento: Navigation static page directly to specific product

Tags: magento, static, navigation, product

I would like to add a static link at the navigation bar that can link directly to a specific product.

As I only have one product listing under category "pillow", I wish to set it to go into the product directly, skipping the catalog view.

I am aware of two methods, being **URL rewrite management** and **static block**, however I experience problem with both.

For "URL rewrite", it worked but once I update something at the category (e.g. moving the position), the system generate a new "URL rewrite" and delete the my custom one.

For "static block", I do not know what code to put in it. My guess was to add below code, but it doesn't work.

```
{{block type="catalog/product_view" product_id="896" template="catalog/category/view.phtml"}}
```

How do I get it done? Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried adding the static link to topmenu.phtml?

Comment: Thanks. Editing the topmenu.phtml is definitely one of the way that can achieve this. This will be my last resort if I couldn't find another way to tackle this more efficiently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have taken a different approach to the problem which may be helpful. It seems like your end goal is to skip the category view if a category only contains one product. So rather than fussing with hard coding templates or trying to clobber the category with URL rewrite, you can accomplish this using an event observer.

The approach will listen for the `<catalog_controller_category_init_after>` event to fire and check whether the category only has one product. If so it will send the request directly to the product. You will need to add a new extension or modify an existing one.

### etc/config.xml

Create a new node under `config/frontend/events`:

```
<catalog_controller_category_init_after>
    <observers>
        <redirectSingleProduct>
            <class>My_MyExtension_Model_Observer</class>
            <method>redirectSingleProduct</method>
        </redirectSingleProduct>
    </observers>
</catalog_controller_category_init_after>
```

### Model/Observer.php

Create the corresponding method to handle the event:

```
class My_MyExtension_Model_Observer
{
    /**
     * Check whether a category view only contains one product, if so send the request directly to it.
     * @param Varien_Event_Observer $observer
     * @return $this
     */
    public function redirectSingleProduct(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        $category = $observer->getCategory();
        if ($category->getProductCount() == 1) {
            $product = $category->getProductCollection()->addUrlRewrite()->getFirstItem();
            $url = $product->getProductUrl();
            $observer->getControllerAction()->getResponse()->setRedirect($url);
        }
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It sounds exactly what I am after.
I have tried your solution but I couldn't get it to work.
I have created a new module using your code, and make sure the module is enabled by checking system>configuration>advanced, but nothing happened. Do you know what could have gone wrong?

Comment: File location was:

app/code/local/Kinaddition/redirectSingleProduct/etc/config.xml
app/code/local/Kinaddition/redirectSingleProduct/Model/Observer.php
class name was changed to: Kinaddition_redirectSingleProduct_Model_Observer

Comment: @Kin - Sorry, worked for me. Have you tried debugging by outputting the category ID and product count in the observer or anything like that? Just wondering if your observer is configured correctly. Also make sure your Magento caches are disabled.

Comment: Thanks again for reply. I am quite new to magento and coding. Could you please guide me the steps for debugging this? It is much appreciated.

Comment: @Kin - First thing to try: rename your extension using a capital letter instead of lowercase. So it should be RedirectSingleProduct for the extension directory, class name, in your module definition, etc. When you have made your changes, can you update the question with the contents and path names for this extension’s files?

Comment: After renaming, it actually worked. Thanks alot! I renamed to Redirectsingleproduct in the end.